# List-initialization of const references to temporary objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I find I am getting different behaviors for the 2 samples below with g++-4.8.1, when temporaries are bound to an instance of a class:

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
  A(T const& a) : b(a) { }

  T const& b;
};
```

and

```
template <class T>
struct B
{
  B(T const& a) : b{a} { }

  T const& b;
}
```

I find, for the first sample, a bound temporary object persists for the life-time of an instance of A, but this is not the case for an instance of B. Is such behavior correct according to the C++11 standard? Please point to the relevant parts of the standard.

NOTE:
`A` and `B`, as well as the temporaries they bind to are instantiated in an expression. At the end of the expression, they are destroyed, along with the temporary they bind to, that is why their life-time should be the same as the life-time of the temporary.

EDIT: Could this part of the standard explain the discrepancy between the 2 initializations:

> — Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is list-initialized,
>   and the reference is bound to that temporary. [ Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program
>   is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. — end note ]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a complete example?

Comment: The complete example is an expression template class, it would be very long. Replacing { } with ( ) makes the expression template library work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [Example at ideone](http://ideone.com/dNtzfo) that demonstrates that g++-4.7.2 creates a temporary for `B`.

Comment: This is [GCC bug 50025](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such behavior is not correct. See 8.5.4p3 4rd last bullet. This was the case for pre-standard drafts for some time, but is not the case in C++11.

It seems you are confused: In no case there should a temporary be created. Both cases should initialize a reference with another reference. Only in the second case, some pre-standard drafts said that a temporary should be created and bound to the member reference, instead of initializing the reference directly.

(See Number 27 in [this list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3307.pdf)).

Comment: But in which document have the bullets been swapped? Has the ISO-IEC 14882 been updated already?

Comment: @user1095108 swapped in C++11

Comment: [My copy - ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) - from March 2012](http://imgur.com/AG87nXr) has the "...if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary..." bullet before the "...if the initializer list has a single element, the object or reference is initialized..." bullet. It may have been fixed editorially since then, but at least the first revisions of 2011 have the erroneous text.

Comment: This was [Core Working Group issue 1288](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3330.html#1288), fixed in Feb-2012 according to the [N3377 Editor's Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3377.html).

Comment: @Casey then i misremembered. it was a post-C++11 fix. That however should still be implemented in any sensible C++11 implementation.

Comment: @Casey actually I did check the C++11 spec before I said "swapped in C++11", but I wasn't paying too much attention to the words, and missed that it still was saying the wrong thing. thanks for noting

Answer (score 2):

> I find, for the first sample, a bound temporary object persists for the life-time of an instance of A, but this is not the case for an instance of B. Is such behavior correct according to the C++11 standard?

The behaviour of `B` is correct. But the behaviour of `A` is wrong in that the life-time of the temporary *should not* persist till the life-time of object of `A` (or the life-time of `B` in case of `B`).

But as a sidenote, since you're binding a temporary to the member of `B`, be aware! The temporary doesn't exist when the constructor returns, which means what the member refers to, doesn't exist!

Comment: But the temporary is part of an expression and is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in which it is created. The life-time of the temporary should be extended by the expression, not the constructor.

Comment: @user1095108: Yes, so? Did I say disagree?

Comment: The temporary may still exist after the constructor returns, that's what I meant. It is not necessarily destroyed.

Comment: @user1095108: Yes, pedantically speaking. But practically it doesn't make much difference, does it? You can use the member in the same expression (before it ends), but that is very unlikely, isn't it?

Comment: Such use lies at the very core of expression templates. Say `Vector v(Vector(0, 0, 0) + Vector(1, 0, 0));`.

Comment: @user1095108: Interesting. I would like to see such code (which justifies such uses of members which bind to temporaries). Is it open-source (can I see it)?

Comment: There are many expression template libraries. Mine is at https://code.google.com/p/etlmath/ , but there are many others, googling for them will return a ton of results. There is also a wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates . I was going through my code replacing () with {}, then recompiling and noticing it did not work anymore.